# Why x & y == 0 is not true while x = 12 and y = 1?

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have the following code. It is used to do some simple bit manipulation.

```
int x = 12; // (00...01100)

int y = 1;

int result;

result = x & y;

printf("x is %d\n", x); // 12
printf("y is %d\n", y); // 1
printf("result is %d\n", result); // 0

printf("x & y is %d\n", x & y); // 0
printf("!(x & y) is %d\n", !(x & y)); // 1
printf("x & y == 0 is %d\n", x & y == 0); // 0 why not true?
printf("result == 0 is %d\n", result == 0); // 1

printf("size of x & y is %d\n", sizeof(x & y)); // 4
printf("size of result is %d\n", sizeof(result)); // 4
```

Why x & y == 0 is not TRUE?

Comment: Most compilers, with the warning level cranked up, will give you a warning that might explain what's going on here. I'd strongly consider compiling with the maximum warning setting enabled.

Comment: Depends on the language, though in most of them the relative precedences of == and & is stupid (ie such that you need parentheses for the common use, and not for the uncommon use). It's not universal though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator precedence matters here:

```
x & y == 0
```

is equivalent to

```
x & (y == 0)
```

which **is** false.

Comment: Yes, that's my bad. I forgot it. Thanks very much!

Comment: Glad that it helped :) If you accept my answer, this question can close.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with operator precedence in your language.
Does x&y==0 parse as (x&y)==0 or as x&(y==0)?
With x=12 and y=1 the former evaluates to 1, the latter to 0.